# getting the flash hash to persist through redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My basic use case is do some processing, set `flash[:notice]`, and then redirect to a new page. From what I can tell, redirects reset the flash tag (please correct me if I'm wrong). Is there a way to gain persistence? Using sessions isn't an option, and I have hacked around the problem using cookies, but I think there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Does flash[:notice] show up during a render and not a redirect? Are you sure the standard layout is being loaded?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The flash hash persists for exactly one redirect or render. So you should be fine with the default settings.

If you need to keep the flash hash for another request/redirect, you can call flash.keep.

```
flash.keep # keep the entire flash hash around for an extra request.
flash.keep(:notice) # keep just flash[:notice] for an extra request.
```

Comment: Is there any possible reason that this might not always be true (such as sessions being disabled)? It is certainly not the case in my uses (flash[:notice] should be displayed as part of the standard layout, but it isn't visible unless it is set before a render as opposed to a redirect).

Comment: What happens when you explicitly reference flash[:notice] in a view?

Comment: After a redirect? Nothing. If there is no redirect involved, I can see the same string assigned.

Comment: Any chance you're calling flash.discard anywhere? That would result a flash hash not surviving a redirect.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is that you're redirecting multiple times. Keep only makes the flash persist for one extra redirect when it's called.

Comment: Be sure to call `flash.keep` before your second redirect (and after your first). My first try I put it after setting the flash, which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Something to be aware of in at least Rails v3.2.1 is that the flash will persist through a redirect if its not referenced at all through at least 1 redirect and load the same view after.  This is a pseudo code of my recent experience:

```
def some_action

(code that may set a flag to redirect 1 time)

redirect_to action_path if(redirect_flag)
....
end
```

Running this would result in the flash[:message] being present regardless of the redirect.

```
def some_action
logger.debug("Flash[:message] #{flash[:message]}")

(code that may set a flag to redirect 1 time)
redirect_to action_path if(redirect_flag)
....
end
```

During debugging with the logger referencing flash[] it would only show up when the redirect didn't happen.  I could see this being problematic if you added a reference to flash before a redirect and lost it down the line for no apparent reason.

See ruby docs here [(Instance protected method: Use at the bottom)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html)

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had added some logging that logged the flash at the request level, and was confused as to why the flash was no longer preserved through multiple redirects. It seems like if you do want to do something like this, you can read the flash through `request.session['flash']` (at least on Rails 4) and it won't go through the normal accessor, which is what normally marks the flash as having been referenced.