# Custom error redirect, flash notice not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a classic Rails app I tried to handle errors with a custom controller redirecting to the root_path with a flash message.

routes:

```
match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found", :via => :all
match "/500", :to => "errors#internal_server_error", :via => :all
```

Error controller:

```
class ErrorsController < Admin::AdminController
  def not_found
    redirect_to admin_path, notice: "Sorry, reccord not found"
  end

  def internal_server_error
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sorry, something went wrong"
  end
end
```

The error redirect_to admin_path or root_path (I've tried other paths to be sure it's not related)

The admin path just show a dashboard:

```
class Admin::StaticController < Admin::AdminController
  def dashboard
    flash.keep
    byebug
  end
end
```

I tried to add the flash.keep even if there's no multiple redirection. Byebug stops the process to help to see what's happening but flash notice appears nil at this point.

Logs (cleaned a little):

```
Started GET something_not_possible_to_get
Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
Processing by ErrorsController#not_found as HTML
Redirected to the_path
Started GET "/" (root_path)
ByeBug stopping here and notice is nil
continue just render the page as expected but without the notice
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect users getting error (404 or 500) to the root_path or another path, let them know something went wrong with a notification message (flash) but without blocking them on the classic Rails error page. Then I could be able to implement internal errors handling (let say email to the admin/owner of the app for instance).

I tried the keep.flash without success.

Why the notice message is dropped? And why this is happening only with errors (I have a lot of redirect_to with notice that are working fine)?

Comment: According to the logs shared by you, `Redirected to root_path` happens when the user encounters a 500 error, but in your log it says 404 error.

Comment: I try both admin_path and root_path even other paths but the same thing happens. Actually only the rescue method render with the notice.

Comment: I am trying to figure out this as I too want to understand why does it not pass it on redirection, waiting for someone to answer it.

Comment: Yes me too it's very strange, I just want to understand what's happening or what I'm missing. I'm pretty sure it's a little something (as always!)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to create ErrorsController, instead you can catch the error and perform any action you want to.

Also you can use `exception_notification` gem to send error related mails to the configured account.

In application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
   rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found
   rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, :with => :internal_server_error
   #some other errors that can be captured
   #rescue_from ActionController::MissingFile, :with => :render_404
   #rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404
   #rescue_from ActionView::TemplateError, :with => :render_500
   #rescue_from Errno::ENOENT, :with => :render_404
   #rescue_from Errno::EACCES, :with => :render_404

  def not_found
    notify(error)
    redirect_to admin_path, notice: "Sorry, reccord not found"
  end

  def internal_server_error
    notify(error)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sorry, something went wrong"
  end

  def notify(exception)
   ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(request.env, exception,
    data: {message: 'An error occured'}).deliver
  end

end
```

**Setting up exception_notification gem**,

1. Add the gem in Gemfile
2. Setup mail:

production.rb (implement the same in development.rb to test it out):

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  #Action Mailer configuration to send emails
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "google.com",
    :user_name => "xyz@gmail.com",
    :password => "123",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true 
  }
end

   MyApp::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[error in]",
    :sender_address => %{xyz@gmail.com},
    :exception_recipients => %w{xyz@gmail.com}
  }
```

3. Check the code above in Application Controller at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try your exemple with rescue just to see if notice is render. But your answer didn't cover completely what I'm asking: why notice disappear? What if I want to implement my custom error controller to handle this? I'll check the code of the gem you mentioned to see how they achieve this.

Comment: Upvote: With rescue the notification message is there. I still want to understand why the custom controller didn't get the same result ;)

Comment: I guess it was getting redirected twice in you case as you were not capturing the error but appended your own method.

Comment: That's what I think too and that's why I tried using flash.keep which is design for this purpose. But basically it's just a controller redirecting to another one and the notice get dropped somewhere. Flash.keep should pass the message.

Comment: keep only makes flash persist for one more redirect. You can read the comments in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1579904/3863146), so I think there are more than 2 redirects happening in your case. I have added the code for setting up `exception notification` gem also

Comment: I'm aware of this behavior. In my case I just do one redirection and not multiple, like when you update something and you redirect or render the show view for the element updated and use flash to tell the user (you didn't need flash.keep in this case). An even if I use flash.keep at all controllers level the notice is not there. I put my logs you can see that there are no multiple redirections. It's just strange an only happening when you try to handle errors. You can test this in a fresh app.

Comment: `rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError` is not working there a lot of posts about this you need to catch in the routes all the "missing routes" and redirect to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use these routes,

```
match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found", :via => :all
match "/500", :to => "errors#internal_server_error", :via => :all
```

You have to set the exception handler in application.rb:

```
module RailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```